# Running a program in debug without hard coding DEBUG = True in Python

Tags: python, bash, debugging, flask

I have a small "Hello World" Flask script that takes an output from a program, called `rescuetime_api` and puts it on a URL `/blog`. I wanted to run the script in Debug mode and hard-coded it into the top of my program but I was wondering if there is a way to pass this value through from my Bash shell. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
#Flask tutorial
import rescuetime_api as api
import os

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

DEBUG = True

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "This is my homepage!"

@app.route("/blog")
def blog():
    result = api.download_rescuetime_json()[1][1]
    return "%s" % result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if os.environ.get("FLASK_TUTORIAL_DEBUG"):
        DEBUG = True
    print "Running in debug:", DEBUG
    app.run(debug=DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script already checks for the environment variable `FLASK_TUTORIAL_DEBUG`.

You could just set it in your shell, before executing the program:

```
export FLASK_TUTORIAL_DEBUG=1
```

and then run your program:

```
python myscript.py
```

And remember to unset the variable when you don't need it:

```
unset FLASK_TUTORIAL_DEBUG
```

Comment: Would I run `python script.py` and then `export FLASK_TUTORIAL_DEBUG=1` or would I want to export the variable before running the script?

Comment: You would need to export it before running the python script.

Comment: Or just `FLASK_TUTORIAL_DEBUG=1 python myscript.py`.